# Authentication error with JPA 2.0 and EclipseLink 2.0

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I'm new to JPA. I'm using maven, eclipselink 2.0 and jpa 2.0. I've created the entities using a database connection. Here's my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="certifications" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/com/ni/ds_edata_soa_nontx</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliCertificationStg</class>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliCertificationStgPK</class>
        <class>com.ni.apps.engineering.certification.entities.NicdsCliUpMapping</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>          
        <properties>                        
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="soa_user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="soa_user"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>           
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is the error I'm getting when trying to run the app.

detailMessage   "Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.1.v20111018-r10243): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException\r\nInternal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: User: NI, failed to be authenticated.\r\nError Code: 0" (id=114)

As you can see, there's nothing called "NI" in my persistence. The only thing that's called NI is the schema from which I'm pulling the tables to create the entities. The JTA datasource is an exact copy of what's in my weblogic.

Any ideas?

--EDIT--
This is how I get the EntityManager

```
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        if(emf == null){
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("certifications");
        }
        return emf.createEntityManager(); //This is where it fails
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using application server provided JTA DataSource, so EclipseLink is getting already initialized EntityManager. I think you do not need additional properties, because that way EclipseLink is creating connection from DataSource as

```
ds.getConnection(username, password);
```

instead as

```
ds.getConnection();
```

Please try to remove properties javax.persistence.jdbc.password, javax.persistence.jdbc.user and javax.persistence.jdbc.driver and ee if it works for you.

EDIT: you are using EclipseLink configured to be used from application server (in your case, WebLogic) because you used JTA DataSource and JNDI lookup to get DataSource connection from application server.
But you use EclipseLink in a way that is meant to be used in non-Java EE environments such as standalone JavaSE clients (please see [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/OutsideContainer)).

If you need EntityManager somewhere, let WebLogic do the initialization, e.g. in Servlet it would look like this:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = { "/Test" })
public class TestServlet {
  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "certifications")
  private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Comment: Tried, but didn't work. I've added a bit more information. Thanks!

Comment: Can you verify from WebLogic console that DataSource connection is working properly? It can be that you use user 'NI' in WebLogic DataSource configuration and its username or password is incorrecly defined in WebLogic.

Comment: No, the weblogic datasource has a completely different user/password combo. It's the same as the ones I had on my persistence.xml